# Does the processor on a router have to handle every single packet?

Tags: router

Or does the router use some sort of shortcut to leave the processor free for other tasks, such as the web interface, dhcp, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, routers generally have a "fast path" that uses dedicated routing hardware for common/mundane packet handling to keep the CPU free for other stuff. Once upon a time, this was only in enterprise-class gear, but modern consumer home gateway routers are often based on SOCs that include dedicated hardware for NAT gateway work. However, in any design, you might have certain configurations or custom rules that cause some kinds of packets to be handled by the CPU because the hardware NAT engine doesn't have support for the custom rule.

If you look at Linux router firmware distros' documentation for how well they support one model of consumer router or another, you'll often see mention of whether or not they support the hardware NAT accelerator available in the SOC in that particular product.

Comment: Nice.  Did not know that.

Answer (score 3):

Purely internal packets (e.g. between your home desktop and your home NAS, each connected to a different port on the home router) may well be switched in hardware.

If this is a modern commercial-grade router, some of the routing could be implemented in hardware / firmware.  You probably don't have one of these at home, but they may well have some routing behavior in dedicated silicon (not the CPU).

Apart from those cases, the CPU is probably involved to get the packet from the network hardware (e.g. radio), evaluate where it should go (route it) and do any additional work needed (e.g. NAT).

However, generally this isn't rocket surgery, and most OSes used for a home router are pretty well optimized for this task.  Generally the packet rate limits imposed by CPU usage are in excess of your upstream bandwidth.